# Wireless LED indicator issue

Tags: wifi, hardware, services, backports

**The question itself**: is there any way to make this indicator be turned ON and OFF depending on wireless status (not just blink when there is wireless activity)?

After having installed Linux, I saw that the wireless LED indicator not working. This problem was in Ubuntu, but now i use Debian (it's awesome indeed!). In Elementary OS 0.2 Luna it worked well, but in the next release 0.3 Freya this issue appeared again.

The only solution I found by now is the following:

```
sudo rmmod -f ath9k
sudo modprobe ath9k blink=1
```

And created a file in order to avoid entering this every time a start the system:

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
```

And wrote the next string in it:

```
options ath9k blink=1
```

But it blinks, that's very annoying! Especially when you have 2 wireless LED indicators (one in the row with other 3: power, , charge, HDD) and the second is on the lid backside. (the **laptop** model: Dell Latitude 3340)

Some information about hardware:

```
yulian@debian:~$ lspci | grep -i wireless
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)

yulian@debian:~$ lspci -vv -s 03:00.0
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
Subsystem: Dell Device 020e
Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 19
Region 0: Memory at f7c00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
Expansion ROM at f7c80000 [disabled] [size=64K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: ath9k
```

---

**Now, the containment of dir `/sys/class/leds`**. There are recursive files (links), so I limited the level to 3:

```
yulian@debian:/sys/class/leds$ tree -l -L 3 -Q > /home/yulian/newDir/out3.txt

.
├── "ath9k-phy0" -> "../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:03:00.0/leds/ath9k-phy0"
│   ├── "brightness"
│   ├── "device" -> "../../../0000:03:00.0"
│   │   ├── "broken_parity_status"
│   │   ├── "class"
│   │   ├── "config"
│   │   ├── "consistent_dma_mask_bits"
│   │   ├── "d3cold_allowed"
│   │   ├── "device"
│   │   ├── "dma_mask_bits"
│   │   ├── "driver" -> "../../../../bus/pci/drivers/ath9k"
│   │   ├── "driver_override"
│   │   ├── "enable"
│   │   ├── "firmware_node" -> "../../../LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:07/device:08"
│   │   ├── "ieee80211"
│   │   ├── "irq"
│   │   ├── "leds"
│   │   ├── "local_cpulist"
│   │   ├── "local_cpus"
│   │   ├── "modalias"
│   │   ├── "msi_bus"
│   │   ├── "net"
│   │   ├── "power"
│   │   ├── "remove"
│   │   ├── "rescan"
│   │   ├── "reset"
│   │   ├── "resource"
│   │   ├── "resource0"
│   │   ├── "rom"
│   │   ├── "subsystem" -> "../../../../bus/pci"
│   │   ├── "subsystem_device"
│   │   ├── "subsystem_vendor"
│   │   ├── "uevent"
│   │   └── "vendor"
│   ├── "max_brightness"
│   ├── "power"
│   │   ├── "async"
│   │   ├── "autosuspend_delay_ms"
│   │   ├── "control"
│   │   ├── "runtime_active_kids"
│   │   ├── "runtime_active_time"
│   │   ├── "runtime_enabled"
│   │   ├── "runtime_status"
│   │   ├── "runtime_suspended_time"
│   │   └── "runtime_usage"
│   ├── "subsystem" -> "../../../../../../class/leds"  [recursive, not followed]
│   ├── "trigger"
│   └── "uevent"
└── "mmc0::" -> "../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:02:00.0/leds/mmc0::"
    ├── "brightness"
    ├── "device" -> "../../../0000:02:00.0"
    │   ├── "broken_parity_status"
    │   ├── "class"
    │   ├── "config"
    │   ├── "consistent_dma_mask_bits"
    │   ├── "d3cold_allowed"
    │   ├── "device"
    │   ├── "dma_mask_bits"
    │   ├── "driver" -> "../../../../bus/pci/drivers/sdhci-pci"
    │   ├── "driver_override"
    │   ├── "enable"
    │   ├── "firmware_node" -> "../../../LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:03/device:04"
    │   ├── "irq"
    │   ├── "leds"
    │   ├── "local_cpulist"
    │   ├── "local_cpus"
    │   ├── "mmc_host"
    │   ├── "modalias"
    │   ├── "msi_bus"
    │   ├── "power"
    │   ├── "remove"
    │   ├── "rescan"
    │   ├── "reset"
    │   ├── "resource"
    │   ├── "resource0"
    │   ├── "resource1"
    │   ├── "subsystem" -> "../../../../bus/pci"  [recursive, not followed]
    │   ├── "subsystem_device"
    │   ├── "subsystem_vendor"
    │   ├── "uevent"
    │   └── "vendor"
    ├── "max_brightness"
    ├── "power"
    │   ├── "async"
    │   ├── "autosuspend_delay_ms"
    │   ├── "control"
    │   ├── "runtime_active_kids"
    │   ├── "runtime_active_time"
    │   ├── "runtime_enabled"
    │   ├── "runtime_status"
    │   ├── "runtime_suspended_time"
    │   └── "runtime_usage"
    ├── "subsystem" -> "../../../../../../class/leds"  [recursive, not followed]
    ├── "trigger"
    └── "uevent"

21 directories, 74 files
```

Comment: Is this an integrated WiFi adapter (e.g., built in to a laptop, not a PCIe card you added to a desktop)? If so, please give the computer make/model as well. Also, do you have anything under `/sys/class/led/`? (Please [edit] your question to add details)

Comment: @derobert, thanks for specify) Newly updated the question.